# How to change the encoding of the message from RETR - POP3

Tags: email, utf-8, header, encode, pop3

I want to change the encoding of the message returned from RETR command in POP3.

I get this header in the reply:

> Content-type: text/html; CHARSET=WINDOWS-1255

I want to change it to:

> Content-type: text/html; CHARSET=UTF-*

Thank you very much. Sorry about my English...

Answer (score 0):

You can't. The POP3 server knows nothing about the encoding of the message - it just stores the message (exactly how it got it) and then hands it over to the client. In fact - theoretically you could retrieve something via POP3, that isn't an email at all.

The encoding of the message is generated at the sending side, not the receiving side.

Comment: it's can't be true , because it is gmail server , and he dislpay the messege in UTF-8 in gmail website.

Comment: It is true. The message **as given by the POP3 server** and what GMails web rendering makes from it are two very different pairs of shoes. If the message was **sent** in Windows-1255, it is easy to convert it to UTF8 for the web rendering, but not the other way round.

Comment: so what to do?i want that the messege will display in hebrew (like in gmail) , but WINDOWS-1255 does not support hebrew

Comment: Your question was: How do I tell the POP3 server to give the message in UTF8 instead of something else. The answer is: You don't, as the POP3 server doesn't know about the message encoding. If you have a different question, I recommend you ask a new question - this is, how SO works. AFAIK Gmail has no option to change the POP3 encoding settings (by regenerating the message)

Comment: so what to do?i must support langueses that is not english in the mailbox.